# navigation 100% spread within a div with even padding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

Hello!

I want to build a website navigation that is 100% spread within a  tag and has even padding. The navigation items have no fixed number, they can be added dynamically. Or even not added, the site will be multilingual, so in different languages the size of the 'li' tags will differ.

I would like to know whether I can use js or jquery or any other method to calculate the sizes of all 'li' elements and give them a width (or padding) that will evenly spread my 'li' elements within the 'div'.

I looked for websites the like and found that cnn.com uses something like this but could not find what exactly.

Comment: So you want to correctly sized div tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Make all of your `<li>` tags inline-block and do text-align: justify on the parent, set to display: block and width: 100%. It should space them all out evenly and you can add whatever padding/margins you want.